# Symbol table in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to write a program for manipulating a symbol table in Java. I've used a linked list data structure as a way to represent my symbol table; the linked list(singly) has a key,value associated to that key, and a pointer to the next point. The linked list also provides to the user the function of inserting a new node to the list. It seems that my implementation for the linked list class is going well, but when I was trying write a main program to test that, I've got some problems. Despite the errors that I managed somehow to handle them with exceptions, there is a logical error in my code. Here is the piece of code that I wrote and the output as well:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test_GPA {
public static void main(String[]args){

     // create symbol table of grades and values
    GPA<String, Double> grades = new GPA<String, Double>();
    grades.put("A",  4.00);
    grades.put("B",  3.00);
    grades.put("C",  2.00);
    grades.put("D",  1.00);
    grades.put("F",  0.00);
    grades.put("A+", 4.33);
    grades.put("B+", 3.33);
    grades.put("C+", 2.33);
    grades.put("A-", 3.67);
    grades.put("B-", 2.67);
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   double numb =0; int i=0;
    double sum = 0.0;
   String grade;
   Double value;
   System.out.println("Please enter number of courses:");
   numb=input.nextInt();
   while(i<numb){
       System.out.println("Please enter the grade for course"+(i+1)+":");
       grade = input.nextLine();
       value = grades.get(grade);
      try{
          sum += Double.valueOf(value);
      }catch(Exception e){}
       i++;

   }
   double gpa = sum/numb;
   System.out.println("GPA = "+gpa);
```

The problem is the code always skips the reading of the first entry by the user. For example, if I run this program and enter the number of courses to be 4, the result will be as shown:

```
Please enter number of courses:
4
Please enter the grade for course1:
Please enter the grade for course2:
A
Please enter the grade for course3:
A
Please enter the grade for course4:
A
GPA = 3.0
```

I don't know actually where is the mistake that I've made. And of course by missing the reading of the first entry that leads to a wrong computation for the GPA. Please, is there anyone interested in showing me how to fix the error. I've tried almost everything i know and it still doesn't work. just FYI, this is the first time i program in Java. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This happens often when trying to read input with a scanner; i think it has to do with the way the method nextLine() works; look around SO for java input problems and see if they solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your implementation of `LinkedList` is not correct linkedlist is not a key-value type of data structure it just links element to other element. I recommend you to look into `HashTable` that is better for this kind of usage. What happens in your code is new-line character does not get consumed when you get input with `nextInt()`. Below code should do the trick

```
numb = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Comment: The problem was in the line of
grade = input.nextLine();
when i changed it to be input.next();
it worked fine.